# show another view controller but save state of current view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to create a small game where the user moves over an object and displays another view controller to display information. Upon pressing a button on the recently presented view controller, the view gets dismissed and shows the view controller I started off with. I've done this like this:

ViewController.m

```
    OtherViewController *other = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"other"];
    [self presentViewController:other animated:YES completion:nil];
```

OtherViewController.m

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

but when i dismiss it, the user starts from the beginning again. is there a way to save where the user is and continue from there?

Answer (score 1):

You're presenting the new view controller as a modal. When you dismiss it, the previous view controller should be uncovered in it's previous state.

If it's not, then you need to look at the logic of your ViewController class.

You want your one time setup code in your viewDidLoad method. If you have code in your viewWillAppear:animated method, or your viewDidAppear:animated method that resets the state of your view controller then that is the problem.

Comment: all i have in `ViewDidLoad` is `[super viewDidLoad];`

Comment: Ok, but what do you have in viewWillAppear:animated? I'm guessing that you're doing your setup there, and that is the cause of your problem. Move your setup code from viewWillAppear:animated to viewDidLoad.

Comment: I don't have viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear

Comment: I don't know then. What you describe does not make sense.